# How to send a cookie in a POST using SHDocVw.InternetExplorer.Navigate?

Tags: c#, cookies, post, shdocvw

Problem:
In our organization we have a home grown single-sign-on app written in c#/.Net2 that has been working for years.  We recently found that the app doesn’t work with Outlook Web Access 2010.  A few web searches turned up a couple articles from SSO vendors ([Novell KB](http://www.novell.com/support/php/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=7006961) and [Citrix KB](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX128197)) that refer to the issue.  OWA2010 executes a javascript on submit that adds a cookie called “PBack=0” that if not included in the post will result in an authentication failure.

Question:
How can I include a cookie in the Navigate method of SHDocVw.InternetExplorer?

```
//ie2 is the instance of IE (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer) containing the OWA login page
ie2.Navigate(URLToPostTo, ref vFlags, ref vTarget, ref vPost, ref vHeaders);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This c# code performs single sign on for owa 2010 in Internet explorer.

```
 AutoResetEvent documentCompleteOW2010;
    void OWA2010LaunchAndSSO()
    {
        var sURL "https://owaserver.yourorg.org/owalogon.asp?

        SHDocVw.InternetExplorer explorer = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
        explorer.Visible = true;
        explorer.DocumentComplete += OnIEDocumentCompleteOWA2010; // Setting the documentComplete Event to false            
        documentCompleteOW2010 = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        object mVal = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        explorer.Navigate(sURL, ref mVal, ref mVal, ref mVal, ref mVal);// Waiting for the document to load completely            
        documentCompleteOW2010.WaitOne(5000);

        try
        {
            mshtml.HTMLDocument doc = (mshtml.HTMLDocument)explorer.Document;
            mshtml.HTMLInputElement userID = (mshtml.HTMLInputElement)doc.all.item("username", 0);
            userID.value = "someADUserName";

            mshtml.HTMLInputElement pwd = (mshtml.HTMLInputElement)doc.all.item("password", 0);

            pwd.value = "someADPassword";
            mshtml.HTMLInputElement btnsubmit = null;
            var yada = doc.getElementsByTagName("input");
            foreach (var VARIABLE in yada)
            {
                var u = (mshtml.HTMLInputElement)VARIABLE;
                if (u.type == "submit")
                {
                    btnsubmit = u;
                }
            }
            btnsubmit.click();

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            //do something
        }
        finally
        {
            //remove the event handler
            explorer.DocumentComplete -= OnIEDocumentCompleteOWA2010;
        }
    }

    private void OnIEDocumentCompleteOWA2010(object pDisp, ref object URL)
    {
        documentCompleteOW2010.Set();
    }
```